# Como coloco margem entre uma imagem e uma lista em HTML?

Tags: html, css, margin

Tentei isso, mas a lista ordenada continua colada a imagem

```
ol {
                margin-left: 5px;
            }
figure {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: 20px;
                }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta colocar `padding` no texto, ou na imagem caso não funcione.

Comment: Link útil: [Diferença entre as propriedades margin e padding do css](http://www.kadunew.com/blog/css/diferenca-entre-as-propriedades-margin-e-padding-do-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema não é exatamente só com a margem, e sim com o `list-style-position: outside/inside;`

Nesse link tem uns exemplos práticos pra vc ver: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp;

Nesse exemplo vc pode entender como funciona a propriedade.

```css
ol.a {
    list-style-position: outside;
}

ol.b {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
ol {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placecage.com/200/100">
<p><b>Lista Outside (pra fora) com o <i>list-style-position: outside;</i></b></p>
<ol class="a">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
<br>
<img src="https://placecage.com/200/100">
<p><b>Lista Inside(pra dentro) com o <i>list-style-position: inside;</i></b></p>
<ol class="b">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: No caso inside, como coloco um espaçamento para que não fique alinhada com o título, mas fique mais para dentro?

Comment: @EricClero o que acontece é que a imagem tem float:left, por isso a margin náo funciona direito a esquerda. Vc pode corrigir isso colocando `display: inline-block` na OL, e ai sim fazer algum ajuste na margin caso ache necessário. Se não der certo é só vc abrir outra pergunta com o seu código atualizado que eu te ajudo beleza. Ai eu não modifica essa resposta que já está resolvida. Testa ai com o display:inline-block e qq coisa me fala ou abre outra pergunta ok que te ajudo.